# MongoDB GridFS bucket?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bucket, gridfs

I work with MongoDB C# [Samus driver](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp).

One of constructors of class MongoDB.GridFS.GridFile has parameter "bucket". When i create GridFile in Java like [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245787/how-to-insert-images-in-mongodb-using-java/4245903#4245903) i cannot set this "bucket". But i can set this "bucket" in Java when create GridFS object [Java documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html). I'm confused!

My question:

What is "bucket"? For what? Tell please some use cases;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bucket is base name for files and chunks collections. By default bucket is 'fs' so you will have two collections:

- fs.files will store file properties like id, name, size, chunk size, md5 checksum etc.
- fs.chunks will store the actual binary data split into chunks, one per document.

Using [GridFS](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html) class constructor argument you can set arbitrary bucket name.

Different buckets can be useful if you need to have separate collections for different types of files, so you can apply different indexes, sharding etc.

Comment: How to add custom gridfs bucket name with mongo shell command ?